# Post extra string through ajax form validation script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a custom variable and value through ajax when the form submission event starts, they have this option when you validate field on blur but when the form is submitted I don't see how to add custom variable to this.

This what they have in on blur validation jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
"ajaxUserCall": {
                    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
                    // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                    "extraData": "name=eric",
```

but there are no options for form submission.

Maybe someone can take look at script and tell me how can i add extra variable with the form?

- [The demo is here](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoAjaxSubmitPHP.html)
- [The script is here](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js)
- [Settings for script](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js)
- [The home page is here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Answer (score 0):

Separate extra Post data with the & separator.  For example:

```
name=eric&this=that&lastname=johnson
```

It's the same way you add extra GET data in a plain php/html form, except with ajax you pass post data the same way.  Was this your question?  Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: specifying extra string to pass is only possible when plugin check field on blur event when you submit form event there is no way to specify extra variable. I need someone who knows javascript to take look at code and understand how to do add additional variable to ajax when submitting form. and its only to validate i cannot have it in form...